# perf instruction count

Tags: perf, assembly

so i've been playing with perf and assembly i have the following program:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

.global _start
_start:
  mov cl, 2
  mov ebx, 0b101
  shr ebx, cl
  and bl, 1 
  je do_stuff

  do_stuff:
  mov eax, 1
  mov ebx, 0
  int 0x80
```

and when I use it with `perf -e instructions:u ./shift`
it shows 9 instructions instead of 8, I could not find why is that.
is there any way to find out which is the +1 instruction?

is it just one of the program instructions but running in parallel then the cpu retires it?
if thats the case how can observe how that works at a lower level?

compiling with: `as -msyntax=intel -mnaked-reg shift.s -o shift.o && ld shift.o -o shift`

`/proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid` set to -1